# asp.net FriendlyUrl and querystring inline handling

Tags: c#, asp.net

i successfully installed `FriendlyUrl` from `Nuget` using `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls -Pre`

now I am trying to do this in my default page :

```
<a href="<%: FriendlyUrl.Href("~/About","Watch") %>">About.aspx</a>
```

but this error occurred : `'FriendlyUrl' does not exist in the current context`

how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following line on top of your page:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls" %>
```